# Bosun + Elasticsearch - How to configure bosun to connect elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, bosun

How can we connect bosun to elasticsearch, is it done through bosun GUI or any config file needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

- ES 2.x
- Bosun compiled from master
- Change bosun.toml according to this http://bosun.org/system_configuration#elasticconf

I can provide more details if you need.

Comment: Bosun supports ES up to 5 now! But you need to compile it yourself with `go build -tags="esv5"`